# extract array inside of jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am currently working to use this JS Lib https://github.com/v-v-vishnevskiy/timeslider and create some different timeline charts.

I want to insert the information for "init_cells" in a generic way so that I don't have to care how many objects (I hope this term is right) are in the array.

In reference to the demo there is this example code:

```
$('#slider123').TimeSlider({
    start_timestamp: current_time - 3600 * 12 * 1000,
    init_cells: [
      {
        '_id': 'c1',
        'start': (current_time - (3600 * 5.4 * 1000) + 1234),
        'stop': current_time - 3600 * 3.2 * 1000,
        'style': {
            'background-color': '#76C4FF'
        }
      },
      {
        '_id': 'c2',
        'start': (current_time - (3600 * 2.1 * 1000))
      }
    ]
});
```

This looks for me like a JSON array of two objects?!

I tried this in the meantime, to store every object in an centralized array.

```
var str1 = [{
      '_id':'c1','start':tV1Start,'stop':tV1End,'style':{'background-color':'#76C4FF'}}];
var str2 = [{
      '_id':'c2','start':tV1Start2,'stop':tV1End2,'style':{'background-color':'#76C4FF'}}];
var arr = [];
arr.push(str1);
arr.push(str2);
```

But how can I extract all the stored inforamtion in the array "arr" inside of the jQuery function for init_cells?

This snipped is not working

```
init_cells:arr
```

But this works:

```
init_cells:arr[0]
```

But how can I create the full timeline by passing the variable arr into the jQuery function without taking care how many elements are inside of the array arr?

Answer (score 0):

That is because in your "centralised array" you are actually storing an array of array of objects—and you actually need an array of objects, without the additional nesting. `arr` is an array, and instead of concatenating `str1` and `str2`, you are pushing them into `arr` instead.

Therefore, your code will produce an incorrect structure that is not recognised:

- Array (this is your `arr`)

  - Array (this is your `str1`)

    - Object
  - Array (this is your `str2`)

    - Object

To fix the issue, use `.concat()` instead of `.push()`:

```
var arr = [].concat(str1).concat(str2);
```

This will then generate the following structure, which is what you need:

- Array (this is your `arr`)

  - Object
  - Object

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra wrapping array for each of your individual objects

Remove the outer `[]` from each like:

```
var str1 = {'_id':'c1','start':tV1Start,'stop':tV1End,'style':{'background-color':'#76C4FF'}};
```

---

If you had this all stored in database and returned full array from database all you would have to do is something like:

```
$.getJSON('/path/to/data', function(responseData){
   $('#slider123').TimeSlider({
         start_timestamp: current_time - 3600 * 12 * 1000,
         init_cells: responseData // pass response data array directly as property value
   });    
});
```